# curl -u equivalent with NSURLRequest in swift

Tags: ios, nsurlrequest

I am using a command of the form:

```
curl -u 'username:password' https://api.myapi.com/something
```

to connect to an html API from the terminal. I want to do the same from my iOS application using NSURLRequest, what is the way?

There is an answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991278/curl-command-to-nsurlrequest-with-username-and-password), yet the answer is in ObjC - I need a swift version of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this.

```
public class WebService{
    var session = URLSession()
    init() {
            let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
            session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)
        }
    public class var sharedInstance: WebService {
        struct Singleton {
           static let instance = WebService()
      }
       return Singleton.instance
    }

     public func fetchAPIData(Username:String!, Password :String!,completion:@escaping (_ responsedata:NSDictionary?,_ error:NSError?) -> Void) {

        var Baseurl = "https://myexample.com"
        Baseurl = Baseurl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
        let weatherRequestUrl = URL(string: Baseurl)
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: weatherRequestUrl!)
         request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        let params:[String: Any] = [

                        "usename":Username,
                        "password":Password
                    ]
        do {
            request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions())
        } catch {

        }
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in

            guard error == nil && data != nil else {

                return
            }
            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse{
                if httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {

                    print("Error")
                }
            }
            do {
                let respondDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data! as Data, options:.allowFragments) as! NSDictionary
                let respondData = respondDictionary["data"] as! NSDictionary
                completion(respondData,nil)
            }
            catch let error as NSError {

                completion(nil,error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()

    }
}
```

Comment: where do I put username and password?

Comment: ¨Make sure to have the NSURLSession initialized correctly (in your code sample above its missing?)

Comment: @Lepidopteron Thanks for correcting me I updated my answer